# Querying Utf-8 with C# by Using Prepared Statement

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8, prepared-statement

Sorry if this question is duplicate and also very simple question. However I can't solve my query problem. I'm new to C# queries. I need to do query like " select * from table where att=N'ğasd' ". I have to use N, otherwise it does not match.

I want to use prepared statement, but when I do something like:

```
commandString = "select * from table where att=N@param;";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "ğasd");
```

It gives " Invalid column name 'N@param' ".

My attribute is nvarchar(50). There is also another interesting thing. Another attribute like att2 is also nvarchar(50) and my database's collation is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", but att2='ğasd' works fine. I solved this problem with adding "N". This time like I said, I stuck on prepared statement problem.

Am I doing something wrong? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `N` part is a prefix for a *literal*. You shouldn't need to to that. I would *expect* this to work:

```
commandString = "select * from table where att=@param";
command.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "ğasd";
```

Note the different way I'm specifying the parameter, to explicitly make it an `NVarChar` parameter. I'd have *hoped* that the right parameter type would have been used anyway, but maybe not...